# Exception when calling a function on the boost::barrier object from another library

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, dll, boost-thread

I've a C++ application which loads a DLL and passes a callback. The DLL creates its own thread, does some tasks and passes a pointer to boost::barrier object to the main application through the callback. But when I call `wait()` on the barrier object, I get an exception `"Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector boost::thread_resource_error> >`.

The same code works fine on OS X. The problem is only on Windows. So I'm guessing there's some Windows specific limitation which I don't know. Google suggested that I may be hitting the limit on the max threads allowed, but my app is not creating more than 20 threads. So I don't think that's the case.

Here are the functions:
**From the DLL:** `s_funPtr(command,s_bar);` s_bar is a static pointer.

**In the main app**

```
PortCallback(CString command, boost::barrier* bar)
{
    bar->wait(); //Throws an exception
}
```

Can you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Have you checked that `bar` is not `NULL`?

Comment: Yes. It's not NULL. Is it possible that it's somehow getting corrupted?

Comment: also check the calling convention (_stdcall or _cdelc).